# Which will be the best way to adapt an web app running in Express to mobile?

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework, mobile, web-applications

I have make a simple web application in express (Node.js) with ejs as a template/view system.

Very simple. For some reasons I need to make that app working on mobile devices just to have some push notifications: chrome notifications works great but some devices (android) have this feature blocked by default also IOS blocks chrome notifications

So the only way is by converting this simple web app into some kind of mobile app. Ionic look's great but you need to adapt your view tags and code..also I don't know if you can combine it with express.

Which will be the best way to adapt an web app running in express to mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I was currently solving the same problem for my new problem you can Convert your Web App to a Mobile App with Apache Cordova , specifically using the Ionic framework, you won't change much on Server side(node.js), however few change as to be made on angular js and very little on view to adapt on ionic design view which very similar to bootstrap tags

Comment: How do you proceed for moving from express to ionic? any tutorial?
thanks!